# LaTeX IDE with git

Tags: ubuntu, git, ide

I currently use Texmaker when working with LaTeX.  I often use Git as well with LaTeX.  I was wondering if there is an IDE similar to Texmaker which supports Git.

Thanks.

P.S. I use Ubuntu.

Comment: There is a big list of [LaTeX Editors/IDEs](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/339/15717), Please choose your's.

Comment: Use `emacs` and `AUCTeX`.  You'll never look back; and in about ten years you'll have learned and subsequently forgotten about more great functionality than most editors have in the first place.

Comment: along @jon lines.[A simpleton's guide to TeX workflow with emacs](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/50827/15717) and [Tips and Tricks by N.N](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/52216/15717)

Comment: Tagging off of what @jon said, I use `magit` to keep everything organized.  It's much better than Emacs' native git support.

Comment: I'm very happy with eclipse+texlipse+egit +texlive+sumatrapdf