# Edit Tabular-like Environment using Emacs+AUCTeX

Tags: tables, best-practices, emacs, auctex

I am using Emacs+AUCTeX to write all my LaTeX files. So far so good except every time when I need to edit some tabular-like environment.

I need some tricks or key bindings to take advantage of Emacs and AUCTex, so that I could be more efficient.

I already know that I can use `C-c C-e` to insert an tabular-like environment, and `M-RET` to quick add `\\` and start a new line. However, is there some shortcut that I can quickly add `&` and indent as I can do in Excel?

Besides, I would be very happy to know other useful tricks to edit tabular-like environments.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: I'd say M-x align-current is very handy. Other than that I think the "tricks" depend on the document/data at hand. The various tools for rectangle formatting is also handy.

Comment: unlike excel you don't actually need to move the focus so to start the next cell you just need `&` and it's a bit hard to have a shorter sequence than that:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I think it can be more efficient and yield more readable code. I think its a good question...

Comment: @Dror I didn't say it was a bad question, I said it was harder to have a shorter key sequence than `&`, which is I hope not a controversial statement:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Of course not :) I think the interesting question is how/whether auctex can format the table easily.

Comment: Have you tried `orgtbl-mode`? You can have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/52284/9517 for an introduction.